# Return the List<myObj> returned by ResponseEntity<List>

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, restful-architecture, resttemplate

My REST client uses RestTemplate to obtain a List of objects.

```
ResponseEntitiy<List> res = restTemplate.postForEntity(getUrl(), myDTO, List.class);
```

Now I want to use the list returned and return it as List to the calling class. In case of string, toString could be used, but what is the work around for lists?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First off, if you know the type of elements in your List, you may want to use the `ParameterizedTypeReference` class like so.

```
ResponseEntity<List<MyObj>> res = restTemplate.postForEntity(getUrl(), myDTO, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyObj>>() {});
```

Then if you just want to return the list you can do:

```
return res.getBody();
```

And if all you care about is the list, you can just do:

```
// postForEntity returns a ResponseEntity, postForObject returns the body directly.
return restTemplate.postForObject(getUrl(), myDTO, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyObj>>() {});
```

Answer (score 17):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work. It seems `postForEntity` no longer has this method signature. I had to use `restTemplate.exchange()` instead:

```
ResponseEntity<List<MyObj>> res = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl(), HttpMethod.POST, myDTO, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyObj>>() {});
```

Then to return the list, as above:

```
return res.getBody();
```

Comment: I confirmed postFor entity is no longer available. Exchange method works

Answer (score 10):

In the latest version (Spring Framework 5.1.6) both the answers are not working.
As kaybee99 mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789276/6866139) `postForEntity` method signature got changed. 
Also the `restTemplate.exchange()` method and its overloads need a `RequestEntity<T>` or its parent `HttpEntity<T>` object. Unable to pass my DTO object as mentioned.

> [Checkout the documentation of the RestTemplate class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)

Here is the code which worked for me

```
List<Shinobi> shinobis = new ArrayList<>();
shinobis.add(new Shinobi(1, "Naruto", "Uzumaki"));
shinobis.add(new Shinobi(2, "Sasuke", "Uchiha");
RequestEntity<List<Shinobi>> request = RequestEntity
            .post(new URI(getUrl()))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(shinobis);
ResponseEntity<List<Shinobi>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            getUrl(), 
            HttpMethod.POST, 
            request, 
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Shinobi>>() {}
            );
List<Shinobi> result = response.getBody();
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **ParameterizedTypeReference** class of Spring to convert to List the data returned by ResponseEntity

```
ResponseEntity<List<MyObject>>  resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){});

if(resp != null && resp.hasBody()){
   List<MyObject> myList = resp.getBody();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unwrap the ResponseEntity and you can get the object(list)

```
 res.getBody()
```

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list

```
ResponseEntity<Team[]> response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(
    this.API_URL(), Team[].class);
```